# Getting key prop warning in React, even though component is not repeated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of components (all containing a unique `key` prop) spread into another list where another component is added at the end.

```
const myComponents = [<myComponent key={1} />, <myComponent key={2} />];
...
return [...myComponents, <myOtherComponent />]
```

I didn't think the `myOtherComponent` would require a `key` prop, but I still get the warning `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop`.

Am I wrong in thinking the `key` prop should be unnecessary in this case?

...should an array containing a single component (`[<myOtherComponent />]`) require a `key` prop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything in an array needs a key when rendered by React. `<myOtherComponent key={0}/>`

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your elements are in an array, this warning will pop up.